# Writing list of list from python to excel but extra line

Tags: python

I am using csv to write a list of list to excel but I am getting an extra line between each list.

My code is:

```
with open("output.csv", "w") as f:
writer = csv.writer(f)
writer.writerows(matrix_)
```

For example:

```
matrix_ = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]]
```

Comment: can you provide the declaration or definition of matrix_

Comment: Please see the update.

Comment: @Mat.S I've run your code. There are no additional lines in between.

Comment: @Mat.S What operating system and what version of python are you using? Is it python2 or python3?

Comment: @Nurzhan I am using python 3.5 in windows 7.

Comment: Can you post what you want as your desired output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using python 3.5 you can try to add a newline parameter to your writer:

```
import csv

with open("output.csv", "w", newline="") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerows(matrix_)
```

Comment: Thanks, last question, how I start to write from B2 instead of A1?

Comment: @Mat.S You're welcome. I need to look at this, I will answer to you soon.

Comment: @Mat.S Sorry, I am a little bit late. I've never had such problem in my experience - to start writing to csv from a particular cell. However, the simplest way is to fill in your `matrix_' with empty lists. If you make your list this way `matrix_ = [[' ', ' ', ' ', ' '], [' ', 1,2,3], [' ', 4,5,6], [' ',7,8,9]]` it will write the data you need from B2.

Comment: @Mat.S You can write a foo loop and depending on the cell you need to start writing from, you add empty lists and spaces to your list as needed. This will be a more flexible solution.

Answer (score 0):

You should set the newline delimiter to `newline=' '` as per the python docs

> csv.writer(csvfile, dialect='excel', **fmtparams)
>   Return a writer object responsible for converting the user’s data into delimited strings on the given file-like object. csvfile can be any object with a write() method. If csvfile is a file object, it should be opened with newline='' [1].

See
https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/csv.html

Hope this helps